# ARC: how to inject custom dealloc IMP in object which in turn calls original dealloc without causing malloc error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to do the following:

1. get a hold to a class'dealloc IMP
2. inject into said class a custom IMP which essentially calls the original dealloc IMP
3. When an instance of said class gets deallocated, both IMPs should run.

This is my attempt:

```
@implementation ClassB

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"\n%@ | %@", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

@end


@implementation ClassC

- (void)swizzleMe:(id)target
{
    SEL originalDeallocSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc");
    __block IMP callerDealloc = [target methodForSelector:originalDeallocSelector];
    const char *deallocMethodTypeEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod([target class], originalDeallocSelector));
    IMP newCallerDealloc = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _caller) {
        NSLog(@"\n new dealloc | calling block %p for %@", callerDealloc, _caller);
        callerDealloc(_caller, originalDeallocSelector);
    });

    NSLog(@"\nswapping %p for %p", newCallerDealloc, callerDealloc);

    class_replaceMethod([target class],
                        originalDeallocSelector,
                        newCallerDealloc,
                        deallocMethodTypeEncoding);

}

@end
```

To be used like so:

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
ClassC *c = [[ClassC alloc] init];
[c swizzleMe:b];
```

But the results are:

**zombie objects disabled:**

```
2013-07-03 13:24:58.368 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
swapping 0x96df020 for 0x2840
2013-07-03 13:24:58.369 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
 new dealloc | calling block 0x2840 for <ClassB: 0x93282f0>
2013-07-03 13:24:58.370 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
<ClassB: 0x93282f0> | dealloc
2013-07-03 13:24:58.370 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
 new dealloc | calling block 0x2840 for <ClassB: 0x93282f0>
2013-07-03 13:24:58.371 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
<ClassB: 0x93282f0> | dealloc
runtimeTest(38626,0xac55f2c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x93282f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2013-07-03 13:24:58.371 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
 new dealloc | calling block 0x2840 for <ClassB: 0x93282f0>
2013-07-03 13:24:58.372 runtimeTest[38626:11303] 
<ClassB: 0x93282f0> | dealloc
```

**zombie objects enabled** (Line 11 is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the picture)

```
2013-07-03 13:34:37.466 runtimeTest[38723:11303] 
swapping 0x97df020 for 0x2840
2013-07-03 13:34:37.467 runtimeTest[38723:11303] 
 new dealloc | calling block 0x2840 for <ClassB: 0x715a920>
2013-07-03 13:34:37.468 runtimeTest[38723:11303] 
<ClassB: 0x715a920> | dealloc
```

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

[image: Line 11 is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

Comment: class_replaceMethod is per class. Replacing a method per instance would imply subclassing

Comment: yes--sorry I missed the part where you extract the class from the instance you pass in.

Comment: You don't mention it explicitly but does turning ARC off fix the issue? I assume it does but I wanted to be sure. Clearly it's deallocating something from under you but I don't have the expertise to determine why. Asking on the Apple Obj-C list or Apple's dev forums if you don't get an answer here may yield better results.

Comment: I didn't try with ARC off yet, but yes, I'd assume without ARC there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is observe the dealloc of certain instances I would instead create an observer to do this, instead of calling through to the dealloc of another instance.

Comment: that's not what I'm trying to do. This is a dummy test case to show the basic idea. I need to be able to inject code in an arbitrary class dealloc and still make sure any original code there might have been in the class dealloc gets executed after the code I inject

Comment: If this is for production code, it is a very bad thing to do as it implies you are trying to modify classes that you don't have the source for.  It will end badly.   What do you need to do in the dealloc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the key problem here is that arc inserts an objc_retain on the caller when I pass it into the original dealloc. I need a way to tell ARC: do not add a retain to _caller as I pass it to callerDealloc

Comment: You could try making it `__unsafe_unretained`

Comment: @bbum is here, I can go now.

Comment: _Wow… serious backlash here._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I finally found the real cause of the problem: I was overlooking the signature of the IMP type. From Apple's Objective-C Runtime Reference:

> IMP A pointer to the start of a method implementation.
>
> id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...)

Particularly, IMP has a return type of id and so in ARCLandia ARC tries to manage this id, causing the `objc_retain` crash. So, assuming you have an IMP to `-dealloc`, explicitly casting it to a C function pointer with return type `void` makes it where ARC won't try to manage the return value anymore:

```
void (*deallocImp)(id, SEL) = (void(*)(id, SEL))_originalDeallocIMP;
deallocImp(self,NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"));
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know *exactly* what your `dealloc` is trying to do.

Comment: pattern is: many instances of different classes want to know when instances of async properties of an "injector" class change and react accordingly, but the code needs to be typed in an async block in-place. So the "injector" has a -notfiy:whenPropertyChanged:^(id p) method. Clients do something like [injector notify:self whenPropertyChanged:^(id p){self.p = p or whatever}]; Internally, the injector registers the callers to observe its properties and injects a KVO observer method which checks if an associated_obj is present in such obj. If it is, the obj has the callback block ^(id p)...

Comment: thing is, if the injected KVO executes, it needs to execute the associated obj block and then deregister the caller so it doesn't execute again. If, for some reason, the caller gets deallocated before the injector updates its property and triggers the KVO, the caller anyway should A - cleanup its KVO registration and B - do any original cleanup it might have had in its dealloc before injection

Comment: Which is why I insist it is not about "knowing when an object gets deallocated." It's about injecting code in an object, then further injecting cleanup code for the injected code in the object's dealloc and further making sure that regardless of the whole injection, any original cleanup code in the object is still being called. Like I said, disabling ARC fixed it, since in my case the problem was ARC adding an objc_retain to the obj although its retcount was already 0 (implied by dealloc being called). However, if you have a better suggestion for achieving what I want, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Yes, the correct solution is to **not inject code at all**.  Swizzling methods and injecting behaviors in this fashion is exceedingly fragile.   You are creating a system where it remaining *working* will require that all of the classes you are injecting code into continue to work the way they do now;  any one of those classes moving to some kind of recycling model or share instances for certain configurations (a la NSNumber) will break your code.  (Don't get me wrong -- it is a brilliant hack... it just incurs massive maintenance risk in a production context. Been there. Done that. Ouch.)

Comment: When I said "arbitrary classes" I should have said "any of a number of custom classes, guaranteed to not change nor to belong to clusters." But regardless, can you think of a better approach?

Comment: Ah -- OK -- so all classes that you own?  Yes, a better approach would be to have a centralized manager that manages the relationships, etc, then have each class call into said manager at the correct times.  Much more explicit and straightforward.   If your classes were to happen to all inherit from NSObject, you could do it only once.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you are talking about one class managing all registered observers inside its KVO, that usually gets slow after 30 objects or so. If I'm misunderstanding you, would you care to maybe post a possible answer explaining your approach?

Comment: That is a deep architectural question and I'm not suggesting any specific solution.   A centralized manager that manages the relationships does not necessarily imply that it plays a role in every message between the items at either end of any specific relationship, just that it manages the comings and goings of said relationships.  Yes, that is remarkably vague because being more specific would require a few hours of thinking about the problem (just as getting to where you are now required quite a few hours, I'd think).

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to know when an object is deallocated, then use associated objects.

Specifically, associate an object with the object you want to observe such that the object being observed has the only strong reference -- the only retain'd reference -- to the object.  Then, you can override `dealloc` and know that when it is called the object being observed has been (or is just about to be) deallocated.

*Do not mess with the object being deallocated, though!!*  It will already have had all of its `dealloc` methods invoked (by inheritance) and, thus, the internal state will be completely undefined.

Note that if your goal is to try and clean up something in the system frameworks, then... don't.   Down that path is nothing instability and pain.

---

> like I mentioned in the comments to nielsbot, I am NOT trying to know
>   when an object is deallocated.

It would be helpful to know exactly what is in your injected `dealloc` implementation.  On the face of it, the only reason I can think of that *couldn't* be solved through the use of associated objects to detect deallocation is exactly because you are trying to change the behavior of a class's `dealloc`, which is a really bad thing to do.

Comment: like I mentioned in the comments to nielsbot, I am NOT trying to know when an object is deallocated.

Comment: This is useful for more than just knowing when an object is deallocated-- you get to add code that runs at `dealloc` time too.